# Is there a way to guess the next number java random?

Tags: java, random

Question is in the title, quite new here so don't know much about the site yet.
Want to use hash for creating "more randomness" but not yet sure about Java's Math.Random() yet, is it possible to crack it?

Comment: See http://franklinta.com/2014/08/31/predicting-the-next-math-random-in-java/

Comment: Your question is not at all clear, please can you explain what it is you want to know?

Comment: What I mean is , is it possible to be able to guess the next number while using math.random() as a function for making random numbers. I wanted to try and improve the method by using hashes if Math.random is insecure.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `java.util.Random()`, it is possible. Have a look at this [Code](https://github.com/fta2012/ReplicatedRandom/blob/master/ReplicatedRandom.java#L15)

For better security, you have to use `SecureRandom` as below

```
SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
```

But the best solution, which can't be cracked is using `Hardware for Random number generation.`

**EDIT:**

Algorithms based on Random like MersenneTwister can be hacked as per this [article](http://www.bishopfox.com/blog/2014/08/untwisting-mersenne-twister-killed-prng/) by `Dan Petro`

`CSPRNGs` (Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator)  to use are:

1. Reading from `/dev/urandom` on a Unix-like system
2. The Java `SecureRandom` class
3. The .NET `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class
4. The PHP `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` function

In contrast, some examples of random number generators to avoid are:

1. The `libc rand()` function
2. The Java Random class
3. The .NET Random class
4. PHP’s `rand()` and mt_`rand()` functions

Have a look at this [article](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) by Thomas Huhn